# Pivot with row wise Sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

TABLE-A:

| PID | BrandName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand1 |
| 2 | Brand2 |
| 3 | Brand3 |
| 4 | Brand4 |
| 5 | Brand5 |
| 6 | Brand6 |
| 7 | Brand7 |
| 8 | Brand8 |

TABLE-B:

| CustNo | Name | BrandName | Qty | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | Brand1 | 3 | 300 |
| 1 | C1 | Brand2 | 2 | 400 |
| 1 | C1 | Brand4 | 1 | 300 |
| 1 | C1 | Brand5 | 2 | 100 |
| 2 | C2 | Brand1 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | C2 | Brand3 | 1 | 200 |
| 3 | C3 | Brand2 | 1 | 300 |
| 3 | C3 | Brand7 | 3 | 150 |

Expected Result:-

| CustNo | Name | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3 | Brand4 | Brand5 | Brand6 | Brand7 | Brand8 | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1100 |
| 2 | C2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 400 |
| 3 | C3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 450 |

Pivot I tried:-

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(BrandName) from [TABLE-A] order by PID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT CustNo,[Name],' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
select CustNo,[Name],Qty,SUM(cast([amt] as float)) as Amt,BrandName from [TABLE-B] group by CustNo,[Name],BrandName,Qty
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Qty)
                for brandname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: What is the question? You've written some code and you are not satisfied with it, so please describe what was wrong. Unless you need a variable number of columns depending on the distinct categories, you can easily use static pivot with enumeration of columns in the `in` part of pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong in your query. First of all you selected column 'Slab' which is not in your table (might by due to copy from another query) Instead you need to select custno and name.

Then your query will run but you will have three rows for for each customer since each customer has three distinct value in quantity field. The reason behind is the group by clause (group by CustNo,[Name],BrandName,Qty) in inner query. Instead I have used window function to sum(amt) for each customer.

I have also used two set of dynamic column names to get rid of null value in the result. One to pivot as you used in your code (@cols) and other list contains coalesce(columnname,0) to convert null into 0.

And if you are using SQL Server 2017 and onward version then I would suggest to use string_agg() to concatenate the column names since it's easier and faster in performance. I have used it in Query#2.

Schema and insert statement:

```
create table [Table-A](PID int, BrandName varchar(50));
insert into [Table-A] values(1  ,'Brand1');
insert into [Table-A] values(2  ,'Brand2');
insert into [Table-A] values(3  ,'Brand3');
insert into [Table-A] values(4  ,'Brand4');
insert into [Table-A] values(5  ,'Brand5');
insert into [Table-A] values(6  ,'Brand6');
insert into [Table-A] values(7  ,'Brand7');
insert into [Table-A] values(8  ,'Brand8');

create table [TABLE-B]( CustNo  int,Name varchar(10),BrandName varchar(50),Qty int, Amt int);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(1  ,'C1',  'Brand1',   3,  300);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(1  ,'C1',  'Brand2',   2,  400);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(1  ,'C1',  'Brand4',   1,  300);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(1  ,'C1',  'Brand5',   2,  100);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(2  ,'C2',  'Brand1',   2,  200);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(2  ,'C2',  'Brand3',   1,  200);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(3  ,'C3',  'Brand2',   1,  300);
insert into [TABLE-B] values(3  ,'C3',  'Brand7',   3,  150);
```

Query#1 (using stuff() and xml path for())

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsForSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
 
SET @colsForSelect = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + ' Coalesce('+quotename(BrandName)+',0) '+ quotename(BrandName)
            FROM [TABLE-A] order by pid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(BrandName) from [TABLE-A] order by PID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT custno,name,' + @colsForSelect + ',Amt
             from 
             (
select CustNo,[Name],Qty,SUM(cast([amt] as float))over(partition by custno) as Amt,BrandName from [TABLE-B]             ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Qty)
                for brandname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Output:

| custno | name | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3 | Brand4 | Brand5 | Brand6 | Brand7 | Brand8 | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1100 |
| 2 | C2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 400 |
| 3 | C3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 450 |

Query#2 (using string_agg() instead of stuff() and for xml path())

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsForSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @colsForSelect= string_agg('coalesce('+BrandName+',0) '+QUOTENAME(BrandName)+' ','  ,') from [TABLE-A]

select @cols = string_agg(QUOTENAME(BrandName),',') from [TABLE-A]


set @query = 'SELECT custno,name,' + @colsForSelect + ',Amt
             from 
             (
select CustNo,[Name],Qty,SUM(cast([amt] as float))over(partition by custno) as Amt,BrandName from [TABLE-B]             ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Qty)
                for brandname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p'

execute(@query)
```

Output:

| custno | name | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3 | Brand4 | Brand5 | Brand6 | Brand7 | Brand8 | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1100 |
| 2 | C2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 400 |
| 3 | C3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 450 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81dc108a3767b3fd3a8e9bda53352ee1)*

Comment: Despite that this solves the problem, it unlikely can help someone except the OP (because requires reader to parse the code with his/her eyes). Please, clarify the problem: what was wrong, what sould be done and why.

Comment: I didn't. I just copied markdown text from dbfiddle.uk.

Comment: @astentx I tried to explain.

Comment: @DaleK I would try to do that form now on. Thanks man.